# I have no car. I don't have a car

Tags: negation, possessives

What's the difference between them, and I know that their meanings or the same but I don't know how they both are grammatical.

- *I have no car.*
- *I don't have a car.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no car.

I don't have any car.

I don't have a car.

You can use "no, not any, or not a" to express the negation of something.

The only difference is that of emphasis.  The use of 'no' makes the negation stronger than that of 'not any' and 'not a'.

Comment: Particularly in British English, you also hear "I haven't a car" (a bit old fashioned) and "I haven't got a car", All have the same meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine, it's a nice addition to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

> I have no car.

You are basically answering **how many cars you have** with a *determiner* "no", which means that you have zero cars.

> I don't have a car.

You are *negating* a **predicate pertaining to having cars.**

Hence they are both grammatical.

Contractions however make it clear that you are saying something with a more informal tone. They should be written out in full (in this case, "do not") if you are writing a formal document.

I see no semantic difference.

> We have no food. I have no money. He has no way to get to work because he has no car.
>
> We don't have food. I don't have any money. He doesn't have a way to get to work because he doesn't have a car.

Comment: "I have no car" is in a more formal register, at least in American English, more formal even than "I do not have a car".